# What city is this on the Apple TV screensaver?

Tags: identify-this

[My dad and I saw this video on the Apple TV screensaver](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qb8Mk6XZ7lkaRNw1J2M43j5WZdhcM2PB/view?usp=sharing)

Can anyone figure out what city this is? Here is the first still:

[image]

Things I've noticed: Right side driving, bulb-shaped marina at the beginning, a lot of skyscrapers that look modern.

I know you can find out if you press a button on the remote while the video is playing, but we have lost our remote and missed the chance.

Comment: FYI While you may be sincere in your question, I'm not going to download a random file from a google drive of a random person.  Ideally you need to create a single image of that file and attach it directly to your question.  Alternatively link to a well know public resource such as a video on youtube.

Comment: Note that you can swipe on the touchpad of the remote when the screensaver is active to scroll through all the screensavers currently available (your Apple TV will download new ones on a regular basis and remove others to make space, so you don't always have the same set available), with a description of each.

Comment: A touch on the touch pad displays the video location, if using the latest tvOS.

Answer (score 18):

It's Dubai Marina.

The video starts more or less above the middle of the Al Sayorah St. bridge and the camera heads North East.

If you go to this location in Google Maps and switch to street view, the buildings should look familiar! https://goo.gl/maps/NRbz7wBRqoqcSFtY7

Answer (score 8):

According to [this article](https://www.patentlyapple.com/patently-apple/2016/12/fantastic-new-apple-tv-flyover-screen-saver-videos-debuted-last-night.html), it looks like it's Dubai:

> The two screenshots below are Dubai's downtown waterway shot during the day.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to try [Google Image Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and [Google Lens](https://lens.google.com/) first. Results searching with your image with Google Lens:

You will see many results showing Dubai.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is Dubai. You can find a list of all Apple TV Screensavers at

https://bzamayo.com/watch-all-the-apple-tv-aerial-video-screensavers#4e67172d4c459bf59a58d58c19537c9d

This one is Dubai 5

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find this out for yourself next time, use your remote!

No, not the one you lost. Use the [remote app](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201664) on your iPhone or iPad!  This works just as well to determine which screensaver is showing - a light tap in the touchpad area will do.

For those who might own an Apple TV but yet not have other Apple devices, there are also [Apple TV Remote Apps for Android](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02LKkXT-yfcE6wiDiIGhx3wbu1QTg%3A1611233599097&source=hp&ei=P3kJYLHCAsWvgge0m7CgDg&q=apple%20tv%20remote%20app%20for%20android&oq=apple%20tv%20remote%20app%20for%20android&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgQIIxAnOgUIABCRAjoICAAQkQIQiwM6CwgAELEDEIMBEIsDOgsILhCxAxCDARCLAzoOCC4QsQMQxwEQowIQiwM6CAgAELEDEIsDOgUIABCLAzoLCC4QxwEQowIQiwM6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOggIABCxAxCDAToFCAAQsQM6CAguEMcBEKMCOgUIABDJAzoFCAAQkgM6DgguELEDEMcBEKMCEJMCOggIABCxAxDJAzoICC4QxwEQrwE6BAgAEAo6BwgAELEDEApQ1QtYjFpgxWNoAHAAeAGAAY0CiAG8IpIBBjEuMzEuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXq4AQI&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjx3cjyiK3uAhXFl-AKHbQNDOQQ4dUDCAk&uact=5)

Comment: Requires you to have an apple machine and not everybody may have one.  Other answers give options for everybody to use.

Comment: @Willeke For sure, though having an Apple TV without any other apple device is an odd choice. This isn’t the best option for everyone, but it is the easiest solution for anyone who does have an apple device (and something I do frequently).

Comment: @Joe, this is off-topic, but... I bought my Apple TV because I also have other Apple devices. (Not an iPhone, though, and there is no remote app on the Mac. But I admit to having an iPad.) I also think that the Apple TV is overpriced. However, it will seamlessly let me play videos at 4K/24 with HDR, even though my display does not accept 4K/60 with HDR (due to bandwidth reasons). That is something that I appreciate and that many other devices will not allow. (For example, afaik an Xbox One X has an API that would allow it, but the app writers at Netflix and so do not care enough to use it.)

Comment: You know, there are Apple TV remote apps for android as well...